# Rearrange $x-y=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given the equation $x-y = 1$, I want to rearrange it to solve for $y$. The answer in the learning materials I have is $y = x-1$.

When I try to rearrange the equation myself I go through the following thought process:

$x-y =1$
--- first I think I want to get the x over to the right hand side of the equals sign so that I'm left with the $-y$ on the left side. So I do minus $x$ on both sides:

$-y = 1-x$

---Then I'm thinking that I want to change the minus $y$ to positive $y$. So then I multiply both sides by minus $1$

$y = -1 + x$

--Then I assume I can just switch around the position of $-1$ and $x$ to give
$y = x-1$

My question is: Is this the same thought process that you would go through to solve this simple equation or am I taking too many unnecessary steps?

Comment: This is $\textbf{exactly}$ the thought process you should have. This should develop your intuition as to why the shortcuts taken in converting these two forms of the same equation are valid.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it more simply is this: It doesn't matter whether we solve for $y$ on the right or on the left. Thus, since $y$ is subtracted on the right, add it to both sides, and then subtract $1$ from each side to get $y$ alone over there: $$x-1=y.$$

There you have $y=x-1$, written the other way around.

I guess you could look at the original equation as telling you that taking $y$ away from $x$ leaves a remainder of $1$, which means that $y$ must be just $1$ less than $x$. Translate that sentence from words to symbols, and you have the same answer.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I honestly don't think an answer is needed for this question...

Comment: I think there's profit in looking at the detailed structure of our intuitions about arithmetic. If you find it fruitless, then I guess we differ in that regard. :)

Comment: I think you misunderstand my point ... I believe OP was looking for confirmation in his approach, not a simplification of methodology. Hence, an affirmation was what he desired.

Comment: Ok, I read the question and came to a different conclusion. Thanks, though.

Comment: Thanks both for you comments. I guess I was after both confirmation as well as alternative possible simplifications in methodology. I hadn't thought of how the original equation is telling you that taking y away from x leaves a remainder of 1, which means that y must be just 1 less than x. This was useful :)

Comment: @RushabhMehta I wouldn't be so quick to assume the gender of a user with a genderless username and no profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

Before:

- $x$ is on the left with a plus sign,
- $y$ is on the left with a minus sign,
- $1$ is on the right with a plus sign.

After:

- $x$ is on the $\color{red}{right}$ with a plus sign,
- $y$ is on the left with a $\color{red}{plus}$ sign,
- $1$ is on the right with a $\color{red}{minus}$ sign.

So chances are low that you can do in less than three elementary transformations... (Though you can reduce to two transformations if you allow the reversal $x-1=y$.)

---

My own way to think:

Isolate $y$ in two moves

$$x-y=1\to x=y+1\to x-1=y.$$

($y$ goes to the right to get a positive sign.)